# Throwing exception used string object is not callable,django

Tags: python, django

Getting ERROR:TypeError at /test/

'str' object is not callable

**form view**:

```
class Test(FormView):
template_name = "pkm_templates/main.html"
 form_class = "Testform"
 success_url = '/thanks/'
 def form_valid(self,form):
    title = form.cleaned_data.get("title")
    fkey = form.cleaned_data.get("fkey")
    instance = Buildkb.objects.create(title=title,fkey=fkey)
    for user in fkey:
        instance.fkey.add(user)
        instance.save()
    return redirect("/")
```

**URL:**

```
path('test/',views.Test.as_view(),name="test")
```

for another model i used approch  formview , modelform and url same has this one no exception.

Comment: Can you post your full error?

Comment: what kind of field is `fkey`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#basic-forms), `form_class` is supposed to be your form class object, not it's name:

```
# assuming TestForm is defined in "yourapp.forms"
from yourapp.forms import TestForm

class Test(FormView):
   template_name = "pkm_templates/main.html"
   form_class = Testform

   # XXX you don't need this one since you're
   # bypassing `FormView.form_valid()` and
   # directly returning a redirect...
   success_url = '/thanks/'

   def form_valid(self,form):
       title = form.cleaned_data.get("title")
       fkey = form.cleaned_data.get("fkey")
       instance = Buildkb.objects.create(title=title,fkey=fkey)
       for user in fkey:
          instance.fkey.add(user)
       instance.save()
       # Unrelated, but you should NOT hardcode urls
       # - use `reverse()` instead
       return redirect("/")
```